# Wireless operatin of HP Deskjet 3720

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu, printing, hp

HP Deskjet 3720 installs well on Lubuntu 16.04 through the USB connection. However, the wireless connection fails to operate, even if the following instructions were used:

> To use the Automatic Installer, follow these steps:
>       Download the file to a convenient location (e.g., home directory or desktop, etc).
>       Open a console/terminal and cd to the location where the installer was downloaded. (e.g., cd ~/Desktop)
>       Type in and run this command: 'sh hplip-3.18.4.run'

(form https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/?source=typ_redirect and http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html)

Everyting worked perfectly including the USB connection and scanner. However, after selecting some options manually for wireless operation it turned out that there was no connection nor support (if I remember correctly) of wireless operation.

Comment: Isn't wireless operation for the HP printer is achieved through the settings on the printer? It needs to connect to your router.

Comment: You should not use hplip from internets, it packaged - so `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` will be enough. And of course check settings on your printer and your router.